# Post hidden field value in Anjularjs and get in PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

Hello i am try to post hidden value but its not post or i not getting in php.
Here is my both code Html with Angular and PHP.
So i check result in ajax_function.php page but i got only text box value not getting hidden field value.

```
<input type="text" name="Addon_Name" id="Addon_Name" ng-model="formData.Addon_Name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Addon_Price" id="Addon_Price" ng-model="formData.Addon_Price" />

<input type="hidden" name="someData" ng-value="data" />

<button type="submit" value="123" id="btn_Addon">Submit</button>
```

`<?php
    print_r($_POST); 
    ?>`

```
<script>

    var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);

    function formController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Hidden_Addon = "1";
        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.processForm = function() {

            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'ajax_function.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData), 
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (!data.success) {
                        alert(data);
                        // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                      //  $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                      //  $scope.errorSuperhero = data.errors.superheroAlias;
                    } else {
                    alert(data);
                        // if successful, bind success message to message
                       // $scope.message = data.message;
                         //           $scope.errorName = '';
                       // $scope.errorSuperhero = '';
                    }
                });
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i already post code but not show here ,

Comment: why do you need hidden input? There actually isn't a  way to bind that to data model but usually you don't need to because you can set the property and value in the data model ... in this case `$scope.formData.someData =??`

Comment: @VuralAcar that will have no effect because there is nothing to bind it to `$scope.formData`

Answer (score 0):

yes hidden value not post value in anjularjs but we can bind some value and its value using in php function.

like that.
$http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'ajax_function.php',
                    data    : $.param($scope.formData)+"&Hidden_Addon=Yes", 
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                })